# multiple template tables in one query of google bigquery

Tags: google-bigquery, temp-tables

I have a query in SQL in this  format:

```
WITH table1(definition1) AS (SELECT statement1),
     table2(definition2) AS (SELECT statement2),
     table3(definition3) AS (SELECT statement3),
SELECT statement;
```

In which I have multiple temp tables in a single query.
Is there any equivalent query for this types of queries ( WITH ... AS) in google bigquery?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[WITH clause](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/sql-reference/query-syntax#with-clause) is available in BigQuery Standard SQL (see [Enabling Standard SQL](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/sql-reference/enabling-standard-sql))

Answer (score 1):

Yes, see the documentation on [WITH clause](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/sql-reference/query-syntax#with_clause) using standard SQL. For example,

```
WITH T1 AS (
  SELECT x, y
  FROM UNNEST([1, 2, 3, 4]) AS x WITH OFFSET y
),
T2 AS (
  SELECT x, y
  FROM UNNEST([3, 4, 5, 6]) AS x WITH OFFSET y
)
SELECT x, t1.y AS y1, t2.y AS y2
FROM T1 t1
JOIN T2 t2
USING (x);
```

To execute this query, uncheck "Use Legacy SQL" under "Show Options" in the UI.